# Windows 10 Store App - save URI as file

Tags: windows, save, uri, windows-10, voice-recognition

I am writing a Windows 10 Store app. In the app the User can input a Text, and then press "Read Text" and Cortana reads the text loud. That works fine.

Now I want to add the feature, to press a button called "Save" or something like that and then save Cortanas output as mp3 file. This should work via a normal save-file dialog.

This is what I got so far.

```
private static MediaElement mediaplayer = new MediaElement();
/// ... mediaplayer element gets content ...
Uri file = mediaplayer.Source;
```

Instead of an Uri element I could also get an SpeechSynthesisStream with this information.

How can I save this Uri / Stream to a file?

**EDIT:**

this is the final code:

```
var stream2 = stream.CloneStream();

//... use stream2 as mediaelement ...

if(stream != null)
        {
            using (var reader = new DataReader(stream))
            {
                FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
                savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

                savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("WAV", new List<string>() { ".wav" });

                savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "sound.wav";
                StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

                if (file != null)
                {
                    using (var outputStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        using (var writer = new DataWriter(outputStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
                        {
                            long writtenBytes = 0;
                            const int bufferSize = 8192;

                            uint loadedBytes = 0;
                            while ((loadedBytes = (await reader.LoadAsync(bufferSize))) > 0) //!!!
                            {
                                IBuffer buffer = reader.ReadBuffer(loadedBytes);
                                writer.WriteBuffer(buffer);
                                uint tmpWritten = await writer.StoreAsync(); //!!!
                                writtenBytes += tmpWritten;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to write the output to a file instead (or as well as) rendering it audibly to a MediaElement, you probably want something like this in here as well.

```
  SpeechSynthesisStream synthesisStream = await synthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);
  var stream2 = synthesisStream.CloneStream();

  FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
  savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;

  savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("WAV", new List<string>() { ".wav" });

  savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "sound.wav";
  StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

  using (var reader = new DataReader(synthesisStream))
  {
      using (var outputStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
      {
          using (var writer = new DataWriter(outputStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
          {
              long writtenBytes = 0;
              const int bufferSize = 8192;

              uint loadedBytes = 0;
              while ((loadedBytes = (await reader.LoadAsync(bufferSize))) > 0) //!!!
              {
                  IBuffer buffer = reader.ReadBuffer(loadedBytes);
                  writer.WriteBuffer(buffer);
                  uint tmpWritten = await writer.StoreAsync(); //!!!
                  writtenBytes += tmpWritten;
              }

          }
      }
  }


  // Set the source and start playing the synthesized audio stream.
  media.AutoPlay = true;
  media.SetSource(stream2, synthesisStream.ContentType);
  media.Play();
```

The one problem is that the synthesisStream isn't rewindable (so far as I can tell), so you might have to synthesize it twice, or make a second (in memory) copy of the stream if you want to make it audible at the same time.

Comment: I changed the code a little bit, so i got a picker to select the position of the file. (the user gets an normal save dialog)

I don't get any error, but the result file is corrupted.

This is my code: http://pastebin.com/YT5tSX83 (don't worry, I'll add the code to the question, if i found the answer)

Comment: Did you reuse the same SpeechSynthesisStream that you put into the MediaElement? Or create a second one? If you reused it, it's possible that they're stepping on each other.

Comment: yey! I commented the MediaElement and now I am able to save the file!

Comment: This is how I copied the stream: `var stream2 = stream.CloneStream();`

Comment: Hm. Okay. I just tried something like what you're doing, and updated my answer. This works for me, the file is valid when it's created, and the playback works properly here. As long as you clone the stream before you start playback and saving, it should work fine, regardless of the order you use.